# Composer Autoload including incorrect versions

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, composer-php

I'm trying to use composer to maintain files for a simple Wordpress plugin. The plugin code uses three files:

- `dmg_custom_menu_widget.php` - the file that requires classes and registers the widget with Wordpress
- `WP_Custom_Menu_Widget.php` - the main widget class
- `WP_Widget_Base.php` - extended by `WP_Custom_Menu_Widget.php`

I use composer to install the plugin code and fetch the dependency.

If files are included by `dmg_custom_menu_widget.php` using the composer autoload file like this:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

I get a 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method...' because it is including an old version of `WP_Widget_Base.php` used by another widget plugin outside of the base directory of dmg-custom-menu-widget.

If files are included directly by `dmg_custom_menu_widget.php` using:

```
require_once 'vendor/DMG/WP_Widget_Base/src/WP_Widget_Base.php';
require_once 'src/WP_Custom_Menu_Widget.php';
```

I get no errors because the correct file is included.

This is the relevant folder structure:

```
plugins/
  dmg-related-pages-widget/
    vendor/
      DMG/
        WP_Widget_Base/
          src/
            WP_Widget_Base.php     <- File being included
  dmg-custom-menu-widget/
    dmg_custom_menu_widget.php     <- Calls require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'
    vendor/
      autoload.php                 <- Composer autoload file
      DMG/
        WP_Widget_Base/
          src/
            WP_Widget_Base.php     <- File that should be included
```

**Additional info**

If the folder `dmg-related-pages-widget` is deleted, the correct file is included.

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "name"      : "DMG/WP_Custom_Menu_Widget",

    "license"   : "GPL-3.0",

    "repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://dgifford@bitbucket.org/dgifford/wp_widget_base.git"
        }
    ],

    "require":
    {
        "DMG/WP_Widget_Base"    : "dev-master"
    },


    "autoload":
    {
        "classmap":
        [
            "src/WP_Custom_Menu_Widget.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add you `composer.json`? I think you added the autoloading for this plugin yourself, right?

Comment: I've added the composer.json file. Autoloading done by composer.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the correct `vendor/autoload.php` is being included.

Maybe your problem is that your working directory is `dmg-related-pages-widget`, and when `dmg_custom_menu_widget.php` includes `vendor/autoload.php`, it loads the file in `dmg-related-pages-widget` not the one in `dmg_custom_menu_widget`. This can happen if there is another script that includes `dmg_custom_menu_widget.php`. In PHP, working directory will be where the PHP interpreter was issued by default, or "document_root" in case of a web server.

To check if this is the problem, add `chdir(__DIR__);` before including `vendor/autoload.php` in `dmg_custom_menu_widget.php`. If it works, then you know the problem. There is also `getcwd()` function to help temporary change working directory.

There is another possibility, that the wrong `vendor/autoload.php` is included somehow before `dmg_custom_menu_widget.php` includes the right `vendor/autoload.php`. This means, the wrong autoloader registers before the correct one, and tries to load classes first. So the wrong class is loaded first.

Comment: I checked that the correct autoload.php file was used by using an absolute path. But your answer led me to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598258/composer-autoload-always-comes-first and the realization that two composer autoloaders were being initiated and the last to be registered in `dmg-related-pages-widget` was loading the out of date version of the dependency. Not sure if I should mark your answer correct - it isn't but led to the right answer?

Comment: That `$prepend`! Anyway, it is your choice to mark it as the correct one, maybe edit it so that it includes the behavior of Composer's autoloader. An upvote would be nice though.